# Find a family of linear inequalities for which the unit ball is a solution set

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, normed-spaces

> Find a family of linear inequalities for which the unit ball $A = \{x \in \mathbb R^n \ | \ \|x\|_2 \le 1\}$ is a solution set

Would it just be $x_1^2 + ... + x_n^2 \le 1$?

Comment: That's not a linear inequality.

Comment: Oh right, it has to be in the form Ax $\le$ b. Thanks for the help I'll keep trying.

Comment: Note that a key feature of the problem is that it asks for a "family" of inequalities, not a "finite set" of them.

Comment: Would an intersection of possibly infinite half spaces work? Just not sure how to find those halfspaces

Comment: Take all the halfspaces tangent to the ball. Imagine cutting it out of a block of wood, one saw cut at a time.